# Отсеять числа больше 100

Tags: php

Как можно отсеять числа больше 100 с помощью PHP?

Comment: Чтобы что-то отсеять, надо что-то иметь...

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что вопрос прост, был задан более 3 лет назад, имеет решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (ЧИСЛО > 100)` что-то делаем.

Answer (score 2):

```
$arr = array();
// заполняем
for ($i = 0; $i < 50; $i++)
  $arr[] = rand(0, 1000);
// чистим
foreach($arr as $n => $v)
  if ($v > 100)
    unset($arr[$n]);
```